# Align sticky element to right side of parent element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a sticky toolbar, that is aligned to the right side. But I cant get it to be aligned to that side:

If I use `float: right;` the element beneath gets pulled up, if I use a parent container, that spans over the whole screen width and use `justify-content: end;` And the use `z-index: 10;` or so, screen at that parent element is blocked.

So how do I align that element to the right side most elegantly?

```css
.container {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 1000px;
}

.sticky-element {
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
}

.other-stuff {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky-element">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
  </div>
   <div class="other-stuff">
    Some other stuff that is drawn up if float: right is applied on sticky-element.
    (But shouldn't)
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a `width:max-content` and a `margin-left:auto` on `.sticky-element`, like so:

```css
.container {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 1000px;
}

.sticky-element {
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
  width:max-content;
  margin-left:auto;
}

.other-stuff {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky-element">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
  </div>
   <div class="other-stuff">
    Some other stuff that is drawn up if float: right is applied on sticky-element.
    (But shouldn't)
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add `display: block;` to `.sticky-element` if it's an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the entire sticky content to be flex and aligned to the end to have the elements on the right.

```css
.container {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 1000px;
}

.sticky-element {
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.other-stuff {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky-element">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
  </div>
   <div class="other-stuff">
    Some other stuff that is drawn up if float: right is applied on sticky-element.
    (But shouldn't)
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining Yousouff's `margin-left: auto` trick with `display: grid` did the trick for me.

```css
section {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}

div,
h1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

div {
  position: sticky;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

h1 {
  min-width: 4000px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>stickied</div>
  <h1>ultra wide element Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta eaque sed placeat dolorem eius? Soluta voluptas ducimus porro, impedit temporibus incidunt nulla officia, velit rem, animi praesentium fuga! Illo, illum?</h1>
</section>
```

Don't ask me to explain it because I have no idea what CSS is doing half the time. It's all just guess-and-check until something works.

In my demo I'm layering the elements on top of each other so they vertically center.